# Can't access inner function properly

Tags: javascript

Not sure if this is the right title but should be quick help.

Pretty much I keep on getting errors on testing a function because "TypeError: ParseThis.changeIt is not a function". Here's my code. What am I missing that causing this type error? Thanks!

```
const ParseThis = () => {
    const changeIt = string => string;

    return { changeIt: changeIt() }

}
```

Edit: More details!

Thanks for the help again

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: ChangeIt is indeed not a function. What do you want to  have it do?

Comment: How are you planing to use this function?

Comment: `changeIt` is a perfectly good function.  It returns its input, whatever it is.  The input need not be a string.  The interesting question here is, what did you expect `changeIt()` to return? Is that a typo or did you intend to call `changeIt` on `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return your object, maybe you wanted to return the function and not the result of the call:

```
return { changeIt: changeIt };
```

or this which is more concise:

```
return { changeIt };
```

According to how you are using the translate function, I think you should export it this way:

```
const Translator = {
  const translate = string => string;
};

if (module.exports) {
  module.exports = Translator;
}
```

or this way:

```
const Translator = () => {
  const translate = string => string;
  return { translate };
}

if (module.exports) {
  module.exports = Translator();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is returning an object, so instead of

```
ParseThis.changeIt()
```

You should be doing something like

```
const a = ParseThis();
a.changeIt('some string');
```

But, note that even in your example, `changeIt` in the returning object is not a function.

Probably you are trying this

```
const ParseThis = () => {
  const changeIt = string => string;

  return { changeIt: changeIt};
}
```

Note that I've used `{ changeIt: changeIt}`, setting `changeIt` to a reference of the inner function `changeIt`. And you are using `{ changeIt: changeIt()}` setting `changeIt` to the value returned of the inner function `changeIt`. Those are two different operations.

Answer (score 0):

Return the function instead of calling it.

```
const ParseThis = () => {
    const changeIt = string => string;

    return { changeIt };

}
```

In the original post, `changeIt()` is a call to `changeIt` with no first parameter.  It returns the value `undefined`. To return a function instead of calling it, omit the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze your code.

Let's start from this:

```
const changeIt = string => string;
```

At this point, changeIt is a function that, given a parameter, it returns that a parameter.

Without an arrow function, if we should use the old classic named function, it would be like this:

```
function changeIt(parameter) {
  return parameter;
}
```

What happens if you call `changeIt()` with no parameter? In javascript, when you pass no parameters ot a function, it's like you are passing undefined. So the function will return `undefined`.

Then you have this line:

```
return { changeIt: changeIt() }
```

But as we have seen, `changeIt()` is equal to `undefined`. So your code is equivalent to:

```
return { changeIt: undefined }
```

Which is clearly not a function!

What you probably meant to do, is not returning the result of function invokation, but return the function itself. So, instead that assigning `changeIt()`, just assign `changeIt`:

```
return { changeIt: changeIt }
```

Notice that you repeated twice the word `changeIt`, so you can get rid of this repetition and just write:

```
return { changeIt }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are exporting a function, and not the object containing the nop function. You need to add parenthesis to your dummy:

```
const Translator = () => {
  const translate = string => string;
  return { translate };
};

if (module.exports) {
  module.exports = Translator(); // add parenthesis here
}
```

Alternatively you could run the function you import, but I suspect that would be different from your real Translator api.